# SwiftUI Static method 'buildBlock

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to show this `DiskStatus()` in SwiftUI `ContentView()` but I can't seem to add it. It always shows me this error:

> Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'DiskStatus' conform to 'View'

I have tried other methods but all of them failed and I can't seem to find a way to render it in SwiftUI.

Can someone help me show it in SwiftUI?

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class DiskStatus {
    //MARK: Formatter MB only
    class func MBFormatter(_ bytes: Int64) -> String {
        let formatter = ByteCountFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = ByteCountFormatter.Units.useMB
        formatter.countStyle = ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.decimal
        formatter.includesUnit = false
        return formatter.string(fromByteCount: bytes) as String
    }

    //MARK: Get String Value
    class var totalDiskSpace:String {
        get {
            return ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: totalDiskSpaceInBytes, countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.binary)
        }
    }

    class var freeDiskSpace:String {
        get {
            return ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: freeDiskSpaceInBytes, countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.binary)
        }
    }

    class var usedDiskSpace:String {
        get {
            return ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: usedDiskSpaceInBytes, countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.binary)
        }
    }

    //MARK: Get raw value
    class var totalDiskSpaceInBytes:Int64 {
        get {
            do {
                let systemAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String)
                let space = (systemAttributes[FileAttributeKey.systemSize] as? NSNumber)?.int64Value
                return space!
            } catch {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }

    class var freeDiskSpaceInBytes:Int64 {
        get {
            do {
                let systemAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String)
                let freeSpace = (systemAttributes[FileAttributeKey.systemFreeSize] as? NSNumber)?.int64Value
                return freeSpace!
            } catch {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }

    class var usedDiskSpaceInBytes:Int64 {
        get {
            let usedSpace = totalDiskSpaceInBytes - freeDiskSpaceInBytes
            return usedSpace
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
  
        DiskStatus()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot include a `class` in a `View` hierarchy like this. Check out some SwiftUI tutorials (Apple, Hacking with Swift, etc) for examples of how to build SwiftUI views.

Comment: Also, there's no point to creating an instance of `DiskSpace`. It only contains class properties and methods, no instance properties or methods.

Comment: @HangarRash do you know a way to modify the code so it can be shown in SwiftUI View!